# Python-PyDev Installation Pre-requisites

Tags: python-2.7, pydev, eclipse-mars

OS: Windows 7 Professional
JDK: 1.7.0
JRE: 7

According to PyDev.org the Pre-requisites for PyDev are:
Eclipse SDK 4.6.0 (Neon),****I have Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)****
Git and Java 8.0. ****I have Java 7.0****

It is my understanding that other versions of those may work but the details may differ and may need manual fixing.I installed PyDev via the "Install new software' in Eclipse Mars and received no errors. However, when I checked the install via Windows > Preferences it was not there. According to http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html Java 7 is acceptable. Could my problem be with Eclipse Mars and, if so, does anyone have fix suggestions?

Comment: That's a **bug** in the install page -- I updated the download page and forgot to update the install page -- will do that before the next release (you really need java 8 for the latest PyDev).

Comment: I have installed Java 8, Python 3.5.2, and PyDev 5.3.0. I am having the toughest time downloading Eclipse 4.6 (Neon). The download for this package continues to fail. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Well, there's LiClipse (http://www.liclipse.com) which comes with PyDev and Java builtin (and some other whistles) -- although it's commercial (with a 30 day trial).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the case that Eclipse plugins requiring Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) and Java 8 can be made to run on earlier releases or with Java 7. These are hard requirements (especially the Java 8).

According to the PyDev home page:

> PyDev 4.5.5 is the last release supporting Java 7

So you either have to use PyDev 4.5.5 or upgrade to Eclipse 4.6 and Java 8.